# Worklight Native Application C2DM_ERROR RuntimeException

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I have an application running in a prod environment and recently I am seeing a lot of RuntimExceptions for C2DM_REGISTERED an C2DM_ERROR. This is really frustrating as its causing the
application to crash in a production environment. I am trying to at least determine if its a bug
in the worklight native api or my application so that I can get things in motion for a fix. We are
using worklight version 6.0.0.20131129-1705. For further info, we are using push notifications on the devices and they are working correctly.

here is the stack trace for the exceptions from both:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent 
{ act=com.x.y.z.C2DM_REGISTERED      
flg=3D0x10 (has extras) } in com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush$3@42c503e8
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:778)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit=
.java:1209)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com=
.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush$3@42c503e8
at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:667)
at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1758)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java=
:475)
at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush$3.onReceive(WLPush.java:385)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:768)
... 9 more



java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent 
{ act=x.y.z.C2DM_ERROR flg=3D0x10 (has extras) } in 
com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush$4@43253ff0
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:778)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit=
.java:1209)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com=
.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush$3@43266650
at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:667)
at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1758)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java=
:475)
at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush$4.onReceive(WLPush.java:407)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:768)
... 9 more
```

Comment: I have push notifications on the device setup in the way that the worklight documentation has shown to use to do it for native applications. I have wondered the same question but assumed it was out of my control since the framework is doing all the setup work. Which version of worklight  did the switch from C2DM to GCM take place?

Comment: Look at page 11 of this document and it shows to set up a receiver for c2dm. Is this an outdated document? http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/07_05_Using_Worklight_API_for_push_notifications_in_native_Android_applications.pdf

Comment: C2dm is outdated. Try to find a doc for gcm.

Comment: Its not a matter of c2dm being outdated. Its a matter of having to use what the worklight native api allows me to use.

Comment: so looking into this further, the worklight framework is using gcm on the device. The C2DM_ERROR and C2DM_REGISTRATION appear to be names made by the Worklight API library and do not signify that we are using the outdated c2dm.

Comment: Can you please share the sample app where you see this problem

Comment: @user2209056, is this resolved? if not, can you provide a sample application to be debugged? or at least your implementation for push support? (androidmanifest.xml, .java files where you register for push)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include this permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```